Is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
I am getting an error

Type '{ key: string; icon: ForwardRefExoticComponent<Omit<LucideProps, "ref"> & RefAttributes<SVGSVGElement>>; label: string; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

I tried fix it but I could not, please Note because I'm new to react,
mycode the error

please share the code instead of images, also share the minimal reproducible code

Hi share a minimal_reproducible_code
